# Can a user with added role of admin invite friends to that fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a fan page, but I have 10 friends. My friend Mary (who also likes and follows my fan page) has 800 friends.

Being the fan page creator, I understand that I can promote my fan page by inviting my 10 friends to it.

My question is: if I make my friend Mary admin of my fan page, can she promote it and invite her friends?

Or is there any other way for Mary to invite her friends to my fan page?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**.

Mary can invite her friend even if she is not an admin of that page or has not like or follow the page.

If she (or anyone) visit your page (or any other page), she will see **Invite friends to like this Page** option on page on the left hand side. By clicking on that she can invite her friends to like your page.

And as an admin she can do more things including inviting friends to like the page.

Answer (score 2):

**Inviting friends to like a page doesn't require admin access.**

Any of your fans could invite their friends to like your page, and they don't have to be your friend.

Admins access is **only** required if Mary is going to:

- Manage Page roles and settings,
- Edit the Page and add apps,
- Create and delete posts as the Page,
- Send messages as the Page,
- Respond to and delete comments and posts to the Page
- Remove and ban people from the Page
- Create ads
- View insights
- And see who published as the Page